# Determine if a `String` is an isogram

Tags: python, pattern-matching

To determine if a string is an isogram:

> Determine if a word or phrase is an isogram. An isogram (also known as
>   a "nonpattern word") is a word or phrase without a repeating letter,
>   however spaces and hyphens are allowed to appear multiple times.

My attempt:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    word = string.lower()

    if word == "":
        return False
    elif word == " ":
        return False
    else:
        for char in word:
            if (word.count(char) > 1) and (char != " " or char != "-") and (len(word) > 0):
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

However this fails when the string passed to the function is empty and when the 2 centre characters are identical.

These are the unit tests:

```
import unittest
from isogram import is_isogram

class IsogramTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_empty_string(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram(""), True)

    def test_isogram_with_only_lower_case_characters(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("isogram"), True)

    def test_word_with_one_duplicated_character(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("eleven"), False)

    def test_word_with_one_duplicated_character_from_end_of_alphabet(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("zzyzx"), False)

    def test_longest_reported_english_isogram(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("subdermatoglyphic"), True)

    def test_word_with_duplicated_character_in_mixed_case(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("Alphabet"), False)

    def test_hypothetical_isogrammic_word_with_hyphen(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("thumbscrew-japingly"), True)

    def test_isogram_with_duplicated_hyphen(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("six-year-old"), True)

    def test_made_up_name_that_is_an_isogram(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("Emily Jung Schwartzkopf"), True)

    def test_duplicated_character_in_the_middle(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("accentor"), False)

    # Additional tests for this track

    def test_isogram_with_duplicated_letter_and_nonletter_character(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("Aleph Bot Chap"), False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What is it that I have done wrong in catering for these 2 test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your errors are at:

(1)

```
if word == "":
    return False
...
```

and (2)

```
char != " " or char != "-"
```

and (3)

```
else:
    return True
```

(1): Your test says that an empty string is an isogram, so this `if` should return `True`

(2): This is a tautology, because it'll always return `True`. Consider the case that your `char` is an empty space, then `char != " "` will be `False`, but `char != "-"` will return `True`, and `True or False` is `True`.

(3): If the first letter of your string does not have a duplicate, it returns True without parsing the other letters of the string. So you should put this return only when the for loop finishes.

So, fixing this things, your code will work fine:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    word = string.lower()

    if word == "":
        return True
    elif word == " ":
        return False
    else:
        for char in word:
            if word and char not in ' -' and word.count(char) > 1:
                return False
        return True
```

And the result from your tests:

```
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

---

PS: You could also rewrite this code to a simpler one as @Ajax1234 and @MoxieBall suggested.

Or you could do something like:

```
def is_isogram(word):
    filtered_word = filter(lambda x: x not in ' -', word.lower())
    return len(filtered_word) == len(set(filtered_word))
```

Comment: you can tidy up that `if` condition as `word and char not in ' -' and word.count(char) > 1`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @MoxieBall. Edited!

Answer (score 4):

It is much simpler to use `collections.Counter` and `string.ascii_lowercase` to only check alphabetical characters:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

def is_isogram(s:str) -> bool:
  c = Counter(s.lower())
  return all(c[i] < 2 for i in ascii_lowercase)

tests = [('', True), ('isogram', True), ('eleven', False), ('zzyzx', False), ('subdermatoglyphic', True), ('Alphabet', False), ('thumbscrew-japingly', True), ('six-year-old', True), ('Emily Jung Schwartzkopf', True), ('accentor', False), ('Aleph Bot Chap', False)]
for a, b in tests:
  assert is_isogram(a) == b

print('all tests passed')
```

Output:

```
all tests passed
```

Comment: Could you comment your code to explain what is happening?

Comment: @Artemis The important factor in the problem is that alphabetic characters must only occur once. Therefore, the frequencies for all characters in the input can be found (using `collections.Counter`) , and then a simple check to determine that all alphabetic characters have a count less than two can take place, yielding the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` to remove characters that you allow duplicates of, then compare the length of `list(your_string)` and `set(your_string)`.

```
import re
def is_isogram(s):
    s = re.sub(' |-|_', '', s)
    return len(set(s)) == len(list(s))
```

As for where you went wrong:
You explicitly say `if word == "": return False`, and then `self.assertIs(is_isogram(""), True)`, so I expect this is a simple mistake that you can fix one way or the other. 
It fails whenever the first character is not duplicated because your `for char in word` loop returns `True` if the first character is not a duplicate. You probably want your `return True` after you have checked all the characters.